# How to filter character length on google sheets pivot table

Tags: google-sheets, filter, conditional-statements, character, pivot-table

I have a row in my pivot table set as "topic", which consists of several different topic lines. I am attempting to filter out all the ones that exceed a character limit of 75. I added "topic" as a filter and filtered it as a "less than or equal to" condition, which I set to 75. That method did not work for me, as it removed everything under "topic". Is there a particular way for me to set a character limit specifically to a column on my pivot table? A custom formula that can be implemented into the filter condition would be helpful too.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet, free of sensitive information, showing the desired outcome?